# Stuck on purple screen

Tags: 11.10, boot, freeze, screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Server stuck at black screen after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94694/server-stuck-at-black-screen-after-reboot)

i had just installed version 11.10 of ubuntu on my netbook. i have a intel gma 3150. the installation went well and there's no problem when using the demo mode.

After reboot when the installation finishes, the system wont boot even after trying both generic and recovery mode from the grub menu.however,i noticed that the hdd activity is still going on and i managed to get on to the login screen by  putting the system to sleep mode and wake it up again but this is extremely inconvenient .

After much effort of trying such as uncommenting GRUB_TERMINAL=TERMINAL and GRUB_GFXMODE update intel graphics driver to latest, uninstall lightdm and uses gdm, disable plymouth, all the effort failed. the only thing work is nosetmode and i915.setmode=1 xforcevesa in the GRUB setting. i managed to boot straight in, but graphics acceleration, splash screen is lost. my default screen resolution which is 1024X600 changes to 1024X768 and i cant change it back. tried fresh installation for 5 times but problem still persist. can anyone help me please?

Comment: I do have exactly the same problem, with a netbook with intel gma 3150. Did you find a solution ?
Best regards.

Comment: what netbook do you have?  if its a nvidia/intel optimus then this PPA may help - https://launchpad.net/~mtron/+archive/eee1015pn

Comment: alternatively - I know that support for your chipset is being worked on upstream - maybe adding the x-edgers PPA could help?  https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa

Answer (score 0):

This answer is exactly this one: [Server stuck at black screen after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94694/server-stuck-at-black-screen-after-reboot/94766#94766) placed here for  your convenience.

> Maybe something wrong with the GPU feeding data. See this answer:
>   [Black screen after updating Ubuntu 11.04 and Mobility HD 4250](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64734/black-screen-after-updating-ubuntu-11-04-and-mobility-hd-4250/64758#64758)
>   which leads to the [X/Troubleshooting/Blank screen Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen),
>   containing useful information to solve these issues.
>
> What I did to solve of GPU feeding data failure was editing the
>   `grub.cfg` file by dropping the next in a terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
> ```
>
> As mentioned on "**Workaround B**" in the Wiki page. Then remove the
>   "`splash`" word on each grub's entry. And the problem was solved.
>
> You can either edit grub.cfg file via Live Session with a CD/DVD or
>   USB bootable. And there are some other workarounds that may help you.

There are some other workarounds on the Wiki Page.

I hope this give you a clue and you find a solution soon.

Good luck!