# Blank screen but can still hear sounds?

Tags: sound, hp, radeon, ati

- CPU: AMD K14
- Ram: 4.00 GB DDR3 @ 671MHz (9-9-9-24)
- Motherboard: Quanta 2AC7 (CPU 1)
- Graphics: HP Omni 120 (1600x900@60Hz) AMD Radeon HD 6320 Graphics

I am trying to install Ubuntu 11.10 inside Windows. When I boot up, I click esc and it takes me to the menu to choose which option I want. I choose 'Demo Mode', just to see if it would come up - it did not. I replaced 'quiet splash', with 'nomodeset', then booted it. A bunch of text comes up on screen, then it goes black.  About 15 seconds later, I can hear the login sound playing, but it is a completely black screen. I can press my volume buttons on my keyboard, and I can hear it making a sound when I turn it up.

If it is a brightness problem (which I don't think it is), I have no way to increase brightness from my keyboard, nor monitor.

I'm not sure what's wrong, but it's bugging me!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/94694/server-stuck-at-black-screen-after-reboot/94766#94766 Maybe something's wrong with the X Server-GPU feeding data which can be solved efficiently by following the steps on the X/Troubleshooting/Blank screen Wiki, at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen. Please inform if you succeed. Good luck!

Comment: I've previously tried all of those workarounds, and none seem to work.  I can't get into a terminal because I cannot install Ubuntu.  However I can edit the command line before I start 'demo mode'.  Any other recommendations?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the brand name and model of your system, if it is related to a Desktop equipment you can try removing the GPU. Otherwise: try connecting an external monitor to your laptop in order to see if the GPU is handling the output via the external devices first, this means that you can change the behavior in the BIOS. Add as much information of your equipment as you can provide.

Comment: Check out this:  http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c03028724&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=135&contentType=SupportFAQ&prodSeriesId=5146275&prodTypeId=12454

All of my Computers info

Comment: I also have no way to add or remove anything considering I don't have it installed, and cannot install it.  I run it inside Windows.  I have a Ubuntu folder in my C:\ Drive.  Otherwise all I can do is edit the command line of 'normal mode' 'non graphical mode' 'demo mode', and theres a couple more.
I can also bring up the command prompt by clicking 'c'

Comment: Well, I am understanding that you are trying to install Ubuntu from inside of Windows, am I wrong? This way I may suggest you to start the install process directly booting from the Live CD. Which may result in a different response from your system. Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Previously I have tried installing Ubuntu from booting it, and I had the same exact problem.  If I installed from CD, and used nomodeset, a purple screen with the ubuntu logo, and 4 loading dots would come up, then about 2 minutes later it'd go blank.

I did manage to install 11.10 with the alternate version, but then when I tried to start it - the same thing happened, it goes blank.

I installed 10.14 just fine, everything worked - however I don't like it - and I couldn't update it.  that's why i want to use 11.10

Comment: I don't have enough ideas this time. I know there are some ways to install directly from terminal and I hope somebody can provide you with a guide or something. Additionally I can mention that I have faced this in the past, and I solved by installing lubuntu (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu) On which you can enjoy both Unity and Gnome DM, it's installed via a non graphical user interface and it is lightweight but powerful. There are also some other distros that you may wish to try. And I suggest you to check twice your install for a corrupted disk or something. Good luck!

Comment: Ubuntu Minimal CD may be another good idea on how to install Ubuntu on  your computer. Check it out at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD#A32-bit_PC_.28x86.29, it's just 20 MB install that fits in any USB Memory and the install process runs like a charm.

Comment: Well I download and installed the Minimal Installation, however I am having the same problem.  I start it, and it goes to a black screen - except this time I hear no sound.  I can get into recovery mode, where there are 3 or 4 options, but I don't know what to do from there.

Comment: I tested out Lubuntu, and literally had the same issue as I did with Ubuntu.

Comment: Strange, maybe you are experiencing a kind of hardware issue or hardware incompatibility. I can't say for sure. Never tested on an equipment like yours. I just wonder if you experience this only when trying to install Ubuntu or the same with other OS installation. Let's wait for somebody else to provide help on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could try searching this site for the answer before posting as it has happened to many people in your situation.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/98688/black-screen-after-update-ubuntu-11-10