# Lenovo Y500 Dual Booting Ubuntu and Windows 8: Stuck on Purple Screen

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, dual-boot

I'm installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my Lenovo y500 with nvidia geforce 750M using uefi. What I've done so far

1. Regular install with Ubuntu disc. (through legacy)
2. Boot repair (recommended) (through legacy)
3. Boot up in UEFI to OS selection screen

When I boot up I get the OS selection screen, but when I select the ubuntu choice, my screen is stuck on a purple screen.

Nothing responds, no <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Atl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, nothing.

I've tried the following solutions, but have no luck:

1. Updated Nvidia drivers:
   http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-quetzal-nvidia.html That
   got me to the screen with the ubuntu logo and the dots, but soon
   after crashed into a black screen with commands. I can also no longer access login terminal via boot recovery
2. Edited boot command: gfxmode nomodeset did nothing for me
3. Tried to regular boot through recovery: Got to black screen with
   login terminal.  Could login to access system, but still does not
   boot to regular ubuntu.
4. [Stuck on purple screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67464/stuck-on-purple-screen):
   Nothing changed.
5. Tried nvidia answer: [Unable to install Ubuntu on Lenovo Y500](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272570/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-lenovo-y500)
   With this, regular choice boots directly into login terminal, no gui or purple screen freeze.

   1. Tried sudo nvidia-xconfig. Did not visibly change anything.

Note:

1. I am booting in UEFI
2. I did disable srt

Comment: I,too, am getting a Y500 soon. This is an issue that I'd like to see the answer to as well so that I know what I'm getting into ;) The hardware of the Y500 at first glance looks pretty plug-n-play in Linux (go Lenovo!), the only issue I see is with the UEFI BIOS. Unfortunately, I don't have an answer for you. You installed Ubuntu in BIOS-compatibility (legacy) mode, and then turned UEFI back on? Or is it still in Legacy mode? FWIW, a while back I isntalled Ubuntu on buddy's MacBook. Didn't fiddle with the UEFI or anything and it came out just fine. Just had to hold CTRL on boot or something.

Comment: Also, did you disable Intel Smart Response Technology (SRT) in UEFI? The 16GB SSD that comes with the Y500 acts as a very large hard drive cache (essentially) if it's reading from this it may not have all the boot files cached already (as far as I know). On the Ubuntu Help page for UEFI, step 2 is to disable SRT. Also of note: from the UEFI help page it states that only the 64-bit version does UEFI detection.

Comment: It is ok to answer your own question.  This allows you to set the checkmark so the question shows up with an accepted answer in lists etc.

Answer (score 4):

**[SOLUTION - Dual Boot Windows + Ubuntu]**

- I got my ubuntu working, but there are some things wrong with it.
- First, because it's a Lenovo Y500, not all the drivers need will be
     automatically download or even be available so some things won't
     work (i.e. ethernet port, brightness adjust, unity?, etc).
- Second, hibernate works half the time, still don't understand what
     causes it to work/fail.  Suspend does not work for me at all
     (suspend works, but can't wake up correctly)
- So if you are considering using Ubuntu, I would recommend against
  choosing the Lenovo Y500, at least for now.
- Now the solution (starting from Windows only):

  1. Go to BIOS upon startup <kbd>F2</kbd>
  2. Go to the Security menu and turn off Secure Boot
  3. Go to the Boot menu and change boot mode to Legacy AND choose to
     boot UEFI first
  4. Save changes and restart
  5. After restart, select to boot (<kbd>F12</kbd>) into the Ubuntu system via USB
     or CD.
  6. Select Try Ubuntu (both times).
  7. Then install Ubuntu normally with the install program, but DON'T
     restart.
  8. After the installation, do Boot Repair:
     https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair and select the
     recommended option.
  9. After boot repair is finished you can restart and you should be able
     to get into Ubuntu and/or Windows

**The KEY, I found after trying for two days, is to set Boot Mode to Legacy, BUT boot UEFI first and Legacy Second.**

Hope this saved you guys from hours of pain.

Comment: Upboats for you, and if anyone has trouble booting windows after this process, use the below place for assistance configuring grub. Worked for me. http://falstaff.agner.ch/2012/12/18/ubuntu-12-10-and-windows-8-with-secure-boot-mode/